# Can I run the Meteor DDP Server protocol on a Java server?

Tags: java, meteor, server, ddp

I am implementing real time features in an application and I would like to know if instead of reinventing the wheel if there is a Meteor DDP protocol implementation in Java.

Comment: Ok, I have added java and server as keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "could use" you mean legally, then yes, [multiple independent implementations exist](http://meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients). Meteor and its content are [licensed MIT](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/LICENSE.txt) (you can use in any way you want as long as you include the license).

So, using the [DDP doc](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/ddp) and the [DDP specification](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md), nothing prevents you from implementing your own in any place.

Comment: Yes, sorry my question was unclear. I am looking for a Java implementation

Comment: In that case, your question would be off-topic because it asks for an off-site resource.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I didn't know that. Where should I post such questions which need an off-site resource?